# How to overload Coroutines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have static method:

```
public static Init( IEnumerator param)
{
   Box box = InitBox();
   box.StartCorountine(param??)       
}
```

I want to pass param as action to StarCorountine, how to add parameters to IEnumerator param?

I have 2 methods and I wanto to invoke one of them in Init static method and I don't know how to pass method as parameter.

```
private IEnumerator test1()
{
 ...
}

private IEnumerator test2(int i, int ii, ReferenceType t)
{
 ...
}
```

Ok,  let's say that box  simply MonoBehaviour class, initialized from prefab.

```
 private static IEnumerator Wait(Box box, float time)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
            box.Open();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
                    box.Close();
                   yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

            DestroyObject(box.gameObject);

        }
```

I usually use Wait method at Init StartCorountine but  now I must to add one action after close and I thought to overload method at Init StartCorountine

Comment: `param` is `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator `?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit and rephrase it. You should as well post the `Box` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IEnumerator` is the *return* value of a method that is operating as the coroutine, not the method itself

This is a valid call per your example code:

```
Init(test1());
```

And why wouldn't it be, you're invoking `test1()`, it yields and returns a value, you pass that value to `Init()` which you then pass off to `StartCoroutine()`, nothing wrong here.  The rest of `test1()` will get called later as normal.

If what you're trying to do is pass a *method reference* to `Init()` and you want to do this:

```
StartCoroutine(param());
```

You can't.  Well, not in the way you want to.

[`Delegates`](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/delegates) do exist and would cover passing a method reference, but delegates are strictly typed and do not support the sort of variant behavior you seem to want to have. I'm not sure *any* language would support what you're trying to do in this case.  If you wanted to have a strictly defined delegate, sure:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();

void someFunc() {
    MyDelegate p = test1;
    Init(p);
}

public IEnumerator test1() {
    ...
}

public static void Init(MyDelegate param) {
    ...
    StartCoroutine(param());
}
```

But notice how this doesn't cover `test2(...)` at all. This is because test2 has different parameters than test1 and would need a separate delegate, and delegates don't follow inheritance rules, they are *strictly typed*: all parameters must be fully declared (no generics<sup>1</sup>) and can't inherit from each other. To support test2, you'd have to write a *second* `Init()` method that took in a delegate with the three parameters, `int i, int ii, ReferenceType t`, all declared.

<sup>1</sup> Unity runs on .NET 2.0 and covariance and contravariance (the features that allow for things like `public delegate void MyDelegate(<T> obj);`) weren't added to the .NET framework until 4.0 if I remember correctly. Might've been 3.5

Unity 2017 is updated to run on .NET 3.5 (with .NET 4.6 experimental available) and should be capable of covariance and contravariance in generic definitions, although I haven't explored it myself yet.